# confused on output. returning two variables and still prints

Tags: c, function, variables, printing, return

```
int addmult(int ii, int jj){
  int kk, ll;
  kk = ii + jj;
  ll = ii * jj;
  return (kk, ll);
}
void main(void){
  int i=3, j=4, k, l;
  k = addmult(i, j);
  l = addmult(i, j);
  printf("%d, %d\n", k, l);
}
```

[image: The code prints "12, 12".]

I thought that it wasn't possible to return two variables from a function. How does the compiler know to print `ll` instead of `kk`? I know that in the function `ii=3` and `jj=4`, `k=7` and `l=12`, but then it goes on to return two variables.  Could someone please elaborate on why it ends up printing:

```
12, 12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function isn't returning two values, you have stumbled upon the [Comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

```
/**
 *  Assigns value of b into i.
 *  Results: a=1, b=2, c=3, i=2
 */
int a=1, b=2, c=3;              
int i = (a, b);
```

The function is just returning the value of `ll`, you want to use reference parameters to return the two values.

```
void addmult(int ii, int jj, int* kk,int* ll){
  *kk = ii + jj;
  *ll = ii * jj;
}
void main(void){
  int i=3, j=4, k, l;
  addmult(i, j, &k, &l);
  printf("%d, %d\n", k, l);
}
```

Comment: this isn't C, is it?

Comment: woops sorry, needs to pass by pointers, fixed

Comment: @undeadherbs Thank you! i didnt know that you could use the reference parameter to return both values. I would verify your answer but the site redirected me to a question on the comma operate... Thank you for answering tho!

Comment: @undeadherbs never mind it says i can verify it in 3 minutes XD